# How to make style from upper class main?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make this code `<a href="link"><span class="metalink">text</span></a>` to apply only link style, not the class?

`!important` doesn't work/

Comment: Yes - write CSS to reset .metalink CSS to intial

Answer (score 0):

Accidentely found the answer.
Just make in css class look like this `.metalink:not(a:link){}`